# How can I obtain the creation date from a file from my google drive storage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

Ìs there a simple way to just obtain the creation date from a google drive file?

Because I want to compare the dates from a file I downloaded from Google Drive, with the one which is on my drive, so I can automatically download the newer file.

I can already run the Quick Start code from the Google Drive API site.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files you will see a property called `createdTime` which is probably what you want. Make sure that you have included this in your `fields` argument, or have set `fields=*`.